# Dynamically Add Values To Tkinter Menubutton (using list)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I was struggling to find some code that would help me to add values dynamically to a Tkinter Menubutton. After doing a lot of research, I came up with a solution myself and decided to share this piece of knowledge.

Adding items in a menubutton manually is pretty straightforward:

```
menubutton = Menubutton(root, text = "Select")

menubutton.menu = Menu(menubutton)   
menubutton["menu"]= menubutton.menu

var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()

menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = 'a', variable = var1)
menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = 'b', variable = var2)
menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = 'c', variable = var3)

menubutton.pack()
```

However, what if one wants to **add menu options** in *Tkinter Menubutton* **dynamically**?

For eg:

If `list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, then menu options should be `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`

If `list1 = ['a', 'c']`, then menu options should be `'a'` and `'c'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using a **list** and a **dictionary** as follows:

```
menubutton = Menubutton(root, text = "Select")

menubutton.menu = Menu(menubutton)   
menubutton["menu"]= menubutton.menu

# main list holding menu values
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# Creating a dictionary
dict2 = {}

# Add key-value pairs to dictionary
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    temp = {'var'+str(i): list1[i]}
    dict2.update(temp)

# Finally adding values to the actual Menubutton
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = dict2['var'+str(i)], variable = list(dict2.keys())[i])

menubutton.pack()
```